# How to limit a transform scale to the width and height of the parent element in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm triying to make a ripple animation.

This is the class:

```
.ripple {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 100%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    animation: anim 0.5s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    left:5%;
    top:5%;
    transform: scale(0);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and this is the animation:

```
@keyframes anim {
    to {
         transform: scale(2);
         opacity:0;
    }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="red">
    <div class="ripple"></div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck triying to limit the ripple animation so
it doesn't exceed the width and height of the parent
node.

This is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wx25q5bo/1/

What should I change in my code in order to get this effect:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbMEEp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wx25q5bo/2/. I would use a single `div` element with a :pseudo-element ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx25q5bo/3/).

Comment: thanks @chipChocolate.py! Your solution is better than mine with that pseudo-element!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your parent element(`#red`). And change the `position:absolute` to `position: relative`. And I guess you will need to use JavaScript to figure out the click position in next step.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, made the animation occur on hover of #red.
Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uazpzLk8/)

Css

```
#red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#red:hover .ripple {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius: 100%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transform: scale(0);
  margin: 0 auto;
 -moz-animation: anim 0.5s ease-out;
 -webkit-animation: anim 0.5s ease-out; 
}
```